# to_json options[:methods] not working for Model.all

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model with a virtual attribute which I'd like to be included when the model is rendered as JSON. I've done this:

```
def to_json(options={})
  options[:methods] ||= []; 
  options[:methods] << :date_string;
  super(options);
end
```

which adds my `date_string` method to the list of attributes to be rendered when producing JSON.

In my controller, the show action produces the correct result, rendering `date_string` as if it was just a normal attribute:

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end
  end
```

but the index action doesn't include `date_string`:

```
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @projects }
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to get this working? I'm guessing that it's not using the model-specific `to_json` when it renders the collection.

---

**Edit:** Looks like maybe I should be using [`as_json`](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/) now - I'll see if that solves this.

**Edit2:** I don't think `as_json` makes any difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as_json should work.  to_json converts the value to json AND encodes it.  as_json does the conversion without encoding.  Arrays convert their objects without encoding and then encode the entire string in one go so it's your model's as_json() method that gets called when the array is serialised:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L215

I was able to replicate your problem locally and this solution worked for me:

```
def as_json(options={})
  options ||= {} # need this because to_json without options will pass nil to as_json
  options[:methods] ||= []; 
  options[:methods] << :date_string;
  super(options);
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it. I had tried `as_json` before, but without the `options ||= {}` line - that sorted it for me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [ActiveModel::Serialization docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html), it looks like you can override the `serializable_hash` method to include your virtual fields:

```
def serializable_hash(options)
  super(options.deepmerge({:methods => :date_string}))
end
```

Note that this will add it to **all** serialization formats (i.e. JSON and XML).

If that doesn't work, add some logging to see if the method is even being called in the collection case.

Comment: Thanks for this - looks useful too. If I need to serialize to XML at any point I'll have another look.